# Asus wifi6 router is not connecting to fibre modem

Tags: networking, router, modem, fiber

I bought an Asus zen XD4 Mini Wi-Fi 6 router. I have a local fibre connection. The ISP gave me a nameless cheap gpon unit which works as the modem and I connect my router to it. This has been like this for 2 years until I bought the new asus router today. Whenever I enter the static IP details, the router disconnects from the modem and says no internet/disconnected.
Older Reuters such as tp-link, dlink still works as I tested. Also direct gpon to pc connection also works if I set the static up in windows.  I’m wondering if the gpon unit is rejecting the connection. The new router being faulty seems unlikely given it has a good market reputation. What else can I check to determine what needs to be changed?

UPDATE:
My dad has the same gpon and same connection. Except his static in config had a MAC address.I setup the router with his gpon connection and put that MAC address and it worked! Now I don’t know where to find my MAC address! My old tplink router didn’t have a MAC address in the static up config.
I further investigated and found that my dad’s MAC address was very similar to his old router’s MAC address (only one digit difference). This confused me even more.

Comment: What are the specifications of the gpon unit and/or the older router fiber doesn’t have auto negotiatio

Comment: @Ramhound Hi, I don’t know how to check those. Can you please guide? I also posted some update.

Comment: You don’t know the specifications for your old modem?  You will need to call your ISP to provision your new modem.

Comment: @Ramhound hi, I think you misunderstood. There is no new modem. And no I don’t know the configs of the modem  Also do you think there are any clues in the update that I posted?

Comment: I am not asking for the configuration of your old modem.  I am asking for the specification of your old modem.  For instance the model number.  Have you contacted your ISP to provision your new modem?

Comment: @Ramhound Hi, sadly nothing worked. The ISP sent someone to my house and he also couldn't find anything and then after an hour of trying, they found out the modem had mac binding with the old router. They reset it and now it works.

Comment: Yeah; So they basically provisioned your modem.